# Reproject Black hole star perspective from hiDef microlensing image

Tags: numpy, model, physics, reprojection-error

I want to reproject HiDef black hole (BH) light whirpool back to perspective of stars from point of that BH itself. <strike>(Maybe to see our Galaxy from the point of that hole hundred years ago).</strike> How to model it in physical formula?
(I will do the finer-tuned final numpy reprojection by myself at the end.)

(The BH rotation is behind my abilities to add into account in that hobby model. Thank you in advance!)
(Maybe once useful even /w pulsar or other easier to catch high-mass-concentrated object...)

Comment: I found these:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/625360/how-to-retrace-the-paths-of-light-back-in-time-for-light-around-a-black-hole
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5627/light-bending-by-black-holes
I simply want to see the (poor) perspective of the Black Hole (BH) in this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/5640/239122 at the end.

Comment: I found all that "HiDef images" were just "models". (The widest angle size of the BH visible from us is M87 * source.) Anyway - still want the "source background img" of the BH model . Sadly - quiet BH microlensing would be still too "micro" for us...